# Magento 2 : How to show special price and regular price in cart page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, cart, onepage-checkout

I want to show base price and special price both in cart page, right now, by default it just shows special price.
How to show exactly like product page or list page. 
Version 2.1x

Answer (score 3):

copy file from

> ../vendor/magento/module-weee/view/frontend/templates/item/price/unit.phtml

to

> design/frontend/your_theme_name/Magento_Weee/templates/item/price/unit.phtml

and paste this one :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Weee\Block\Item\Price\Renderer */

$item = $block->getItem();
?>
<?php if ($block->displayPriceInclTax() || $block->displayBothPrices()): ?>
    <span class="price-including-tax" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Incl. Tax')) ?>">
        <?php if ($block->displayPriceWithWeeeDetails()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total"
                data-mage-init='{"taxToggle": {"itemTaxId" : "#unit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"}}'>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($item->getProduct()->getSpecialPrice() != null): ?>
                <label style="color: red;">Old Price :</label>
        <p style="color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through;"><?php echo $block->formatPrice($item->getProduct()->getPrice());?></p>
                <?php endif;?>
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($block->getUnitDisplayPriceInclTax()) ?>
            </span>

        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item)): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-info" id="unit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>" style="display: none;">
                <?php foreach ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="weee" data-label="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $tax['title'] ?>">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'], true, true) ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </span>

            <?php if ($block->displayFinalPrice()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total"
                    data-mage-init='{"taxToggle": {"itemTaxId" : "#unit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"}}'>
                    <span class="weee" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Total Incl. Tax')) ?>">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($block->getFinalUnitDisplayPriceInclTax()) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->displayPriceExclTax() || $block->displayBothPrices()): ?>
    <span class="price-excluding-tax" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Excl. Tax')) ?>">
        <?php if ($block->displayPriceWithWeeeDetails()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total"
                data-mage-init='{"taxToggle": {"itemTaxId" : "#eunit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"}}'>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($block->getUnitDisplayPriceExclTax()) ?>
            </span>

        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item)): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-info" id="eunit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"
                style="display: none;">
                <?php foreach ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item) as $tax): ?>
                    <span class="weee" data-label="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $tax['title'] ?>">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($tax['amount'], true, true) ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </span>

            <?php if ($block->displayFinalPrice()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total"
                      data-mage-init='{"taxToggle": {"itemTaxId" : "#eunit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"}}'>
                    <span class="weee" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Total')) ?>">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($block->getFinalUnitDisplayPriceExclTax()) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

use bin/magento cache:clean && bin/magento cache:flush. And all work!!

in my variant path next :

> design/frontend/Smartwave/tropenkost/Magento_Weee/templates/item/price/unit.phtml

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work :(

Comment: LOL, whats all that I can say

Comment: I just tried to add an alert to <?php if ($block->displayPriceInclTax() || $block->displayBothPrices()): ?>
 but it doesnt goes to this line at all. what are you thinking about?

Comment: omg, just copy paste and all will work fine, just copy vendor file to your destination...

Comment: it works for me!  `$item->getProduct()->getPrice()`

Comment: I am very glad to help you!

Answer (score 3):

The above answers are good and work.
I am proving a full answer here with proper solution so it will not affect other sections of the website.

1. create **Magento_Weee** folder at **app\design\frontend\{your_vendor_name}\{your_theme_name}** if folder already not exist.
2. create a folder named layout and inside create a file named **checkout_item_price_renderers.xml** if not exist.
3. Put below line of code into a file.

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
            <body>
                 <block class="Magento\Weee\Block\Item\Price\Renderer" name="checkout.item.price.unit" template="Magento_Weee::cart/item/price/unit.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                       <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">cart</argument>
                    </arguments>
                  </block>
            </body>
        </page>
   ```
4. create a file **unit.phtml**
   at **app\design\frontend\Etales\fashion\Magento_Weee\templates\cart\item\price**
5. And copy paste below line of code into that file.

   ```
        <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

    /** @var $block \Magento\Weee\Block\Item\Price\Renderer */

    $item = $block->getItem();
    ?>
    <?php if ($block->displayPriceInclTax() || $block->displayBothPrices()): ?>
        <span class="price-including-tax" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Incl. Tax')) ?>">
            <?php if ($block->displayPriceWithWeeeDetails()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total"
                    data-mage-init='{"taxToggle": {"itemTaxId" : "#unit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"}}'>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $finalPrice = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice(); ?>
                <?php $normalPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice(); ?>
                <?php if($normalPrice != $finalPrice):?>
                    <p style="color: red;text-decoration: line-through;">
                        <?php echo $block->formatPrice($normalPrice);?>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($block->getUnitDisplayPriceInclTax()) ?>                    
                </span>

            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item)): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-info" id="unit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>" style="display: none;">
                    <?php foreach ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee" data-label="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $tax['title'] ?>">
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'], true, true) ?>
                        </span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </span>

                <?php if ($block->displayFinalPrice()): ?>
                    <span class="cart-tax-total"
                        data-mage-init='{"taxToggle": {"itemTaxId" : "#unit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"}}'>
                        <span class="weee" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Total Incl. Tax')) ?>">
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($block->getFinalUnitDisplayPriceInclTax()) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($block->displayPriceExclTax() || $block->displayBothPrices()): ?>
        <span class="price-excluding-tax" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Excl. Tax')) ?>">
            <?php if ($block->displayPriceWithWeeeDetails()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total"
                    data-mage-init='{"taxToggle": {"itemTaxId" : "#eunit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"}}'>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($block->getUnitDisplayPriceExclTax()) ?>
                </span>

            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item)): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-info" id="eunit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"
                    style="display: none;">
                    <?php foreach ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee" data-label="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $tax['title'] ?>">
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($tax['amount'], true, true) ?>
                        </span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </span>

                <?php if ($block->displayFinalPrice()): ?>
                    <span class="cart-tax-total"
                          data-mage-init='{"taxToggle": {"itemTaxId" : "#eunit-item-tax-details<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $item->getId() ?>"}}'>
                        <span class="weee" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Total')) ?>">
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($block->getFinalUnitDisplayPriceExclTax()) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #shopping-cart-table .item-info .col.price span{text-decoration: inherit;}
    </style>
   ```

coding is done not need to deploy if you are in production mode.

Need to flush the cache.

If production mode than

```
 php bin/magento s:s:d --theme {your_vendor_name}\{your_theme_name} -language {langauge_code}
```

Or just run

```
php bin/magento s:s:d
```

At last clear or flush the cache.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: t doesn't work for bundle products, because they may not have "normal price"

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to override Renderer.php file in core and you should never do in core. You can just changes in sidebar.phtml file and set your changes.

You can get price from below method:

```
$finalPrice = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
$normalPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
```

After getting above changes you can do it below code in your template file:

```
<?php if ($block->displayPriceWithWeeeDetails()): ?>
        <span class="minicart-tax-total">
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="minicart-price">
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatPrice($block->getUnitDisplayPriceExclTax()); ?> 
        </span>

    <?php if($normalPrice != $finalPrice){ ?>
    <span class="minicart-old-price">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatPrice($normalPrice); ?>
    </span>
    <?php }   ?>
```

I have done changes in Magento Version 2.1.1.

another way :
copy file to your theme folder and edit:

> ../vendor/magento/module-weee/view/frontend/templates/item/price/unit.phtml

find :

```
<span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatPrice($block->getUnitDisplayPriceInclTax()) ?>
            </span>
```

get product if from item, and after get special price, and echo it.
like this:

```
$finalPrice = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
$normalPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
echo $finalPrice."".$normalPrice
```

and using css just add styles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to do it on cart page not minicart

Comment: Then you gotta place you template changes inside vendor/magento/module-wee/view/frontend/template/item/price/unit.phtml and do extend it in theme files.
Thanks

Comment: use the same way

Comment: edit answer, working with 2.3 version

Comment: it doesnt work for me, on magento 2.1.9

Comment: mb do you have another theme that override magento theme?? Because I have checked on 2.1.9 version, 5 min ago, and it is working fine

Comment: and share your code here, to try it , because it is unreal to discuss about this without your code example

Comment: <?php if ($block->displayPriceInclTax() || $block->displayBothPrices()): ?>
<script>alert('2');</script>

 Alert doesn't show, it doesn't come in to this line. i'm on luma magento 2.1.9

Comment: It doesn't work for bundle products, because they may not have "normal price"

Answer (score 0):

I can't "add a comment" under the @Padhiyar Gaurang comment yet, but your answer works for me on Magento 2.2.9 except that there is an error on your step 4 :

4. create a file unit.phtml at app\design\frontend\My_constructor\My_theme\Magento_Weee\templates\cart\item\price

It's :

4. create a file unit.phtml at app\design\frontend\My_constructor\My_theme\Magento_Weee\templates\item\price

Now I need to do the same for the minicart widget and the Order Sumary ...